# Can a Zooloretto Enclosure Score Money if Filled Via Enclosure w/ Breeding?

Tags: zooloretto

In the rules for Zooloretto it states that you won't collect money for filling an enclosure through the "exchange" action. It also states that animals of opposite sex will not breed in the barn. If you exchange one type of animal enclosure with another type of animal from the barn (which happens to include the breeding-ready couple), would you receive the coin bonus? My interpretation is that the breeding happens after the exchange, so you would get the bonus, but this is not spelled out in the actual rules. Does anyone have a definite answer on how this situation is scored?

As a side-note, the iOS version of this game would be no help in seeing how the computer scores the situation, as it incorrectly does not let you exchange animals out of the barn (the rules clearly state that you can).

Comment: I could have sworn I have Exchanged out of the barn before, but perhaps I Moved instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question: the rules state that pairs united by an exchange DO breed; and that you DO NOT collect money for filling an enclosure through an exchange action.  It really comes down to whether exchanging-then-breeding counts as "filling an enclosure through an exchange action", or whether the breeding is really subsequent to and distinct from the exchange action.

My gut reaction was that, sure, it's a bit ambiguous, but why not give the benefit of the doubt, don't be cheap, dish out some money.  Fortunately, I managed to find a passage in the rules that proves my gut is an idiot:

> Exception: NO bonus is awarded when
>   all enclosure spaces are filled as a
>   result of an exchange. **There is also
>   NO bonus awarded if an offspring
>   produced by the exchange fills the
>   last space.**

So there you have it!  (Incidentally, I found a useful combined rules pdf online here: http://files.boardgamegeek.com/file/download/48p5z9a045/Zooloretto.pdf?)  You're welcome!